# Read out text in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, text

Is there a way or a lib which can read out text?

Comment: Define "read out". Do you mean text to speech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another one that does text-to-speech and also speech recognition

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out myself yet, but something existed at the end of last year: 
http://www.ahmed-essam.com/2010/11/ios-sdk-text-to-speech-in-one-line.html

Comment: I do not recommend this solution for distribution via App Store because it uses a private framework